# Price on product detail page changed to 0.00 magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: php, database, magento2.4, nginx

I'm facing a weird issue with the product detail page on magento 2.4.3. The product price will be shown while loading the page and changed to 0.000 once the page is loaded completely. The price is correct on the product listing page. Also tried to upgrade the magento version from 2.4.3 to 2.4.3-p1, but still facing the issue.

Thanks,

Attaching the screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: a client of mine had this error with this module of Bss Simpledetailconfigurable

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are struggling with a Bug in Magento 2.4.3 which is discussed in a couple of Magento tickets on GitHub (e.g. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33798 )

Solution would be either a patch as described here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856#issuecomment-904606945

> To make it work on Magento 2.4.3 without having to switch to unstable develop branch, you can create a `patches/composer/ISSUE-33856-magento-disable-currency-number-formatter.patch` file with following content:
>
> ```
> diff --git a/Model/Currency.php b/Model/Currency.php
> index 65b47d7..f9943da 100644
> --- a/Model/Currency.php
> +++ b/Model/Currency.php
> @@ -365,10 +365,6 @@ class Currency extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
>          */
>         $price = sprintf("%F", $price);
>
> -        if ($this->canUseNumberFormatter($options)) {
> -            return $this->formatCurrency($price, $options);
> -        }
> -
>         return $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
>     }
> ```
>
> And then add the following to your composer.json:
>
> ```
> {
>    "extra": {
>        "patches": {
>            "magento/module-directory": {
>                "Disable number formatter for Model/Currency ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856 )": "patches/composer/ISSUE-33856-magento-disable-currency-number-formatter.patch"
>            }
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

OR you make sure that Commit https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ae304d43cd36322b1ff8145d70c9b2e9aeb0cde is in your used Magento version which is supposed to be the final fix for this - according to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856#issuecomment-946761019

Comment: Current version 2.4.3-P1 does not yet contain this fix

Comment: If anyone interested where the preceding suggested patch came from, take a look here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856#issuecomment-904606945

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below solution to fix it:

You need to replace the code of vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml with below code:

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount */ ?>
<?php
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
?>
<span class="price-container <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAdjustmentCssClasses()) ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()) :?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDisplayLabel()) ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()) :?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceId()) ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes()) . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceType()) ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceWrapperCss()) ?>"
        <?= $storeId == 2 ? "style=display:none;" : ''; // here i got this issue in specific store view so i have done it for that store only ?>
    ><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()), ['span']) ?></span>
    <?php if($storeId == 2): ?> <?= // here i got this issue in specific store view so i have done it for that store only ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()), ['span']) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()) :?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()) :?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()) ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Jaydeep
But it is not working, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove this condition `<?= $storeId == 2 ?` on the below lines in the same code, like:

```
<span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()) :?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceId()) ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes()) . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceType()) ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceWrapperCss()) ?>"
        style="display:none;";
    ><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()), ['span']) ?></span>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()), ['span']) ?>
```